# android- smart textview - RTL for arabic/persion sentences and LTR for english sentences

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, android-textview-autosize

I want to make my textView smart that it automatically change the text directon of the sentence to left to right for english sentences and right to left for arabic/persion sentences

this is done in lots of applications like telegram .

I'v tried to pragmatically change the directions but it did changes the whole content

how can I make my textview that much smart?